# bootstrap social media icons above menu

Tags: menu

I am using Bootstrap and trying to get the social media icons above the menu - so far I have:
[image]

What I am aiming for is something like this:
[image]

So the image is at the end - and the menu items are still responsive.
The code I have so far is :

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse header-outer" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="logo1.png " alt="Image" id="logo" class="img-responsive pull-left" />

    <div class="social_media">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left padding-top nextline">  
                <li><img src="facebook.png" /></li>
                <li><img src="twitter.png" /></li>
                <li><img src="linkdin.png" /></li>
                <li><img src="instagram.png" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pull-left padding-top">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button  style="position:relative; left:0;">CONTACT WITH US</button>


  </div>

</header>
```

and the CSS is:

```
<style>

    .social_media {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .navbar{ background:#ffffff; border:none;}
    .nextline { 
        width:80%;
        border-bottom : 1px solid #000000;      
    }
    </style>
```

Has anyone done anything like this???

Comment: Am I right, that your only problem is to get the contact button to the right? Have you tried `<button  style="float:right">`

Comment: Hi Johannes - I have but the button is then half outside the the black line - so the end of the button is not inline with the black line.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put another div around the lower part to group it. Only then you can assure that the contact button can be inline with your underline of the social media section, as you set the width to the same as your `nextline` class. This way you get a container for the part below the line, that has the same width, and you can align the button as you want.
So your code should look like

```
<div class="pull-left padding-top" style="width:80%">
  <div class="pull-left padding-top">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button class="pull-right padding-top">CONTACT WITH US</button>
</div>
```

A simple jsfiddle for whole code

https://jsfiddle.net/87xz8q9x/5/

Hope this helps